# How to conditionally run a @Rule in Java/Kotlin androidx UIAutomation

Tags: android, junit, conditional-statements, rules

I am writing UIAutomation for Android. There is a handy @Rule available in the testing libraries that lets me preemptively grant app permissions so I don't have to deal with permission dialogs when running UI tests on the app.

There is a new permission in Android 13 (sdk33) called 'POST_NOTIFICATIONS'. The app I'm testing uses this capability, but devices running Android 12 and below don't recognize it. So, here's my problem: I have a permissions rule that looks like this:

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule =
        grant(
            "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
            "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
        )
```

It works perfectly when I run the test against an Android 13 device. But when I run it on an Android 12 device, the test crashes right away due to the permissions manager attempting to request a permission that doesn't exist. This unhandled exception comes from the built-in test library code from google -- `GrantPermissionsRule.java` in package `androidx.test.rule` When I change the code as shown below to remove the new permission, it works fine on Android 12, but now the Notifications dialog will appear when I use this code with Android 13 devices.

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule =
        grant(
            "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        )
```

I want to be able to run the tests on both Android 12 and Android 13 devices without changing the permissions code back and forth. So how do I solve this problem?  I don't know much about advanced java/kotlin features, but there doesn't appear to be a way to wrap a @Rule inside a try/catch block so I can handle the exception and execute the abridged code block. And there doesn't appear to be a way to make a @Rule conditional on, say, android device version number, so that I can use the right set of permissions at the right time in the first place.

Do I need to override the builtin androidx library? Or maybe there is a fancy Kotlin or Java **thing** I can use to conditionally add the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission to the set of permissions I end up using inside the @Rule? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```kotlin
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
          grant(
              "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
              "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
          )
        } else {
          grant(
              "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
          )
        }
```

BTW, unless there's something magic about this rule that requires `var`, I would use `val` over `var`.

Comment: This is perfect, and so simple. Thank you! Is the concept of using a conditional like this (after an equals sign) a new concept, or am I just getting old?

Comment: @jerimiah797: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. It has been valid Kotlin syntax for a few years. Basically, `if` can be treated as an expression, though it requires an `else`, and the `if` and the `else` need to evaluate to compatible types. The same thing holds for `when`: it can be used as an expression if it is an "exhaustive when" or has an `else` branch. See [this](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin/pages/chap-branchloop-004.html) for more. I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: I'm new to Kotlin but have used other common languages like Java, Javascript, Python, C++, Ruby, etc. and I find this concept highly unintuitive, even though I think it's great. Just never would have thought of it on my own. :-)

Comment: If you _only_ need POST_NOTIFICATIONS you can fallback to an empty GrantPermissionRule for older SDK versions:

    @get:Rule
    val grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        } else {
            GrantPermissionRule.grant()
        }

Comment: I want to run some tests with permission granted and some with denied. Seems there is no way of configuring the Rule from a test method. I guess I would need a custom rule or separate test classes for that.